# Socket io, cannot get or emit message

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I want to try socket.io for one of my project, the connection is established but i cannot emit or received message between server and client.

```
/*****************************
* NodeJs server
*****************************/
const express = require('express');
const app = (module.exports = express());
// Listen the server
const server = app.listen(app.get(port), function(){ ... })
let io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
// Listen socket
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('your are connected to the chat');
    socket.on('chatmessage', function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
    })
})
```

Below is the client part, which is on my local machine, this just a simple html file with socket.js included :

```
/*****************************
* Client part
*****************************/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <div id="sendChat">Click here</div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        // with my remote ip
        var chat = io.connect('http://x.x.x.x:5001');
        var btn = document.getElementById('sendChat')
        btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
            console.log('i hit the button');
            chat.emit('chatmessage', 'valeur du chat');
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

With this code, my server console output me : "your are connected to the chat" when i open the client. But when i start to emit message by hitting the "sendChat" button from the client (the client console output 'i hit the button') , i receive no message on the server part.
So to illustrate the server console :

[image: server console]

Someone can helps me please?
Note sometimes i get this message too : GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1532094068991-10 404 9.377 ms - 21

Thank you.

Comment: It appears you are using v1.2 in the client.  What version are you running on the server?  You need to run the SAME version at both.  You could change your client code from this `<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>` to this `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` and the client will automatically use the same version as the server, even when you update the server.

Comment: thanks @jfriend but where can i pick this file?

Comment: The route `/socket.io/socket.io.js` is automatically built-into the server version of socket.io.  You don't need any additional files for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are using v1.2 in the client. I'm guessing that is not the version are you running on the server? You need to run the SAME version at both.

You could change your client code from this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

and then the client will automatically use the same version as the server, even when you update the server.  The route `/socket.io/socket.io.js` is automatically built into the socket.io server code so you don't need any additional files or routes for that route to "just work".  This way, whenever you upgrade your server, the client version will automatically upgrade with it (there's a client embedded in the server).

If you want to use a CDN, then you have to manually make sure that the CDN version of the socket.io client is always exactly matched with the server version.